# List files on the workspace on a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to list files in the workspace in a Jenkins Pipeline, so that I can use that to produce appropriate parallel tasks.

While I could simply use `sh ls > files` and read that, I want `File` objects which I can filter further with more complex logic. In fact, `Files.listFiles(FileFilter)` would be ideal.

However, I can't get the list of files at all. First, I had to resort to some weird stuff to simply find out the current work directory for the build:

```
sh 'pwd > workspace'
workspace = readFile('workspace').trim()
```

Now I call this to retrieve the list of files:

```
@NonCPS
def getFiles(String baseDir) {
    Arrays.asList(new File(baseDir).listFiles())
}
```

And get a NPE on `asList`, which means, by my read of the javadoc, that `new File(baseDir)` does not exist (or is not a directory).

I'm tagging it `@NonCPS` because it's required for groovy closures on Pipeline, which I'd really prefer to use over full java <1.8 syntax.

Comment: also there's `pwd()` pipeline func to get current dir.

Answer (score 43):

For pwd you can use [`pwd`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#pwd-determine-current-directory) step.

As for list of files in main workspace dir you could use `findFiles` from the [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/):

```
files = findFiles(glob: '*.*')
```

Comment: `pwd` doesn't work on slaves. It returns the workspace on master.

Comment: and what about findFiles?

Comment: `findFiles` does not return a `File`. It returns a `FileWrapper`, which is rather more limited. It might be useful if it doesn't have a path problem like `pwd`.

Comment: As it happens, `findFiles` doesn't return a full path to the file, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what `findFiles` returns but can't you use it in addition with `pwd` (even your custom implementation) to find the full path of your file(s) ?

Comment: Are you trying to find files which you generated in a previous stage. I just want to mention that I had success with using parallel builds (in my case test jobs executed from pipeline) in connection stash/unstash. I could not understand why the files I just created were gone in the next stage where I wanted to get their contents. Perhaps you are experiencing something similar?

Comment: `files[0].name` just gives you the filename without path. If you want the path to the file you have to convert: `files[0].toString()` (So you can get the file content with `readFile(files[0].toString())`.)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń  I want to access/read all txt files (including sub dir of workspace as well) using groovy postbuild. How to do that?

Answer (score 12):

A solution that works in all cases without the use of JENKINS function

```
def  FILES_LIST = sh (script: "ls   '${workers_dir}'", returnStdout: true).trim()
//DEBUG
echo "FILES_LIST : ${FILES_LIST}"
//PARSING
for(String ele : FILES_LIST.split("\\r?\\n")){ 
   println ">>>${ele}<<<"     
}
```

Comment: I would imagine one would want an OS portable solution. Also, this doesn't handle files or paths with spaces

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example of how I'm finding json files in my project for processing.

```
sh "ls *.json > listJsonFiles"
def files = readFile( "listJsonFiles" ).split( "\\r?\\n" );
sh "rm -f listJsonFiles"
```

- Use ls to find the files and write that to another temporary file
- Read the temporary file and split on new lines to give an array
- Delete the temporary file

Comment: Why not `sh script: "ls *.json", returnStdout: true`?

Answer (score 5):

you can try following which uses pwd() if you are running the script on master.

```
 sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest & uncomplicated groovy solution that has worked for me.

```
def fileList = "ls /path/to/dir".execute()
def files= []
fileList.text.eachLine {files.add(it)}
return files
```

Comment: I suspect, if you run with a build agent, this will show files on the master.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!!

```
node("aSlave") {
    def files = getAllFiles(createFilePath("${workspace}/path_to_directory_in_workspace"))
}


@NonCPS
def getAllFiles(rootPath) {
    def list = []
    for (subPath in rootPath.list()) {
        list << subPath.getName()
        // in case you don't want extension
        // list << FilenameUtils.removeExtension(subPath.getName())
    }
    return list
}

// Helps if slave servers are in picture
def createFilePath(def path) {
    if (env['NODE_NAME'].equals("master")) {
        File localPath = new File(path)
        return new hudson.FilePath(localPath);
    } else {
        return new hudson.FilePath(Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getChannel(), path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jenkins doesn't have to permit File instance to be created.  So, this might fail.

Comment: You can approve it though, if you follow the link in the error log.