# Get a list of filenames in a given folder in Jenkinsfile (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot create a simple list of filenames in a given directory in a scripted Jenkins Pipeline. I tried many Groovy Script examples posted on SO and other forums but either the feature is blocked or I get method not found or whatever.

This seems to be the easiest

```
def DOCKER_FILES_DIR = './dockerfiles'
// ...
def dir = new File(DOCKER_FILES_DIR);
def dockerfiles = [];
dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) {
    dockerfiles.add(it)
}
```

But this resolves the relative path incorrectly, so I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /./dockerfiles
```

I also tried to wrap it in `dir` with:

```
def DOCKER_FILES_DIR = './dockerfiles'
// ...
def dockerfiles = [];
dir("${env.WORKSPACE}"){
    def dir = new File(DOCKER_FILES_DIR);
    dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) {
        dockerfiles.add(it)
    }
}
```

But got the same error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /./dockerfiles
```

This does not give an error, but only adds one file to the list:

```
def DOCKER_FILES_DIR = './dockerfiles'
// ...
def dockerfiles = [];
def dir = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/${DOCKER_FILES_DIR}");
dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) {
    dockerfiles.add(it.getName())
}
```

The contents of `dockerfiles` is then missing all the files but the first one:

```
['py365']
```

Here is a minimal Pipeline to reproduce it in Jenkins:

```
#!groovy
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES

node('master') {
    FILES_DIR = './foo'
    cleanWs()

    sh """
        mkdir foo
        touch foo/bar1
        touch foo/bar2
        touch foo/bar3
    """

    def filenames = [];
    def dir = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/${FILES_DIR}");
    dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 0) {
        filenames.add(it.getName())
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
        def filename = filenames[i]
        echo "${filename}"
    }
}
```

And the output, showing that only `bar1` is printed:

```
Started by user Tamas Gal
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestHome
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] sh
[TestHome] Running shell script
+ mkdir foo
+ touch foo/bar1
+ touch foo/bar2
+ touch foo/bar3
[Pipeline] echo
bar1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: `def files = dir.listFiles()` ?

Comment: That one also gives me just one file...

Comment: It seems that it's similar to the `for each` iteration bugs. No idea what's going on there. This whole Jenkins Pipeline is a mess...

Comment: You can't really do things like `new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/${FILES_DIR}")` and execute with it (see [some info in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/TtaIXm8OUl0/aNfY_6SNAAAJ)). The pipeline Groovy code executes on the Jenkins master while the step actions and commands will be executed will to the agents/executors which usually are not on the same machine.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150211/865033).

Comment: Thanks Venkat but we gave up Jenkins after years of bug hunting and weird scripting issues, security problems (multiple cryptominer incidents). We now have a self-hosted GitLab CI. I really really regret that I wasted so much of my time with Jenkins...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't really make use of the `new File` and normal Groovy/Java ways to traverse file systems. The call is security checked by default (see [JENKINS-38131](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38131)) and won't even generally work because of how Jenkins Pipelines executes your pipeline code.

One way you could do this would be to use the [`findFiles`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) step from the [*Pipeline Utility Steps* plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps). It returns a [`FileWrapper[]`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/0b912dac3870b880d354dcbe0d21cfff4b08ff93/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.java) which can be inspected/used for other purposes.

```groovy
node {
  // ... check out code, whatever
  final foundFiles = findFiles(glob: 'dockerfiles/**/*')
  // do things with FileWrapper[]
}
```

Another option is to shell out and capture the standard out:

```groovy
node {
  // ... check out code, whatever
  final foundFiles = sh(script: 'ls -1 dockerfiles', returnStdout: true).split()
  // Do stuff with filenames
}
```

Comment: what about for windows?

Answer (score 4):

This one works, but it's ugly as hell:

```
#!groovy

node('master') {
    FILES_DIR = './foo'
    cleanWs()

    sh """
        mkdir foo
        touch foo/bar1
        touch foo/bar2
        touch foo/bar3
    """

    def TMP_FILENAME = ".docker_files_list"
    sh "ls ${FILES_DIR} > ${TMP_FILENAME}"
    def filenames = readFile(TMP_FILENAME).split( "\\r?\\n" );
    sh "rm -f ${TMP_FILENAME}"

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
        def filename = filenames[i]
        echo "${filename}"
    }
}
```