# Jenkins : how to run groovy script in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I try to migrate my classic jenkins jobs to pipeline. Actually I have groovy script which read input json. I would like to know how to run groovy script in stage ? I try this but not working :

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('SetEnv') {
        steps {
            environment {
                JSON_BASE_PATH="/json_repo/test"
            }
            echo 'SetEnv..'
            script {
                // Get latest JSON FILE FROM /tmp/*.json
                def file = new File(JSON_BASE_PATH).listFiles()?.sort { it.lastModified() }?.find{it=~/.json$/}
                println ("\nJson file is " + file )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean , run external groovy file in jenkins pipeline or execute groovy  sentences in jenkins pipeline?

Comment: and what exactly `not working` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of filenames in a given folder in Jenkinsfile (Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586769/get-a-list-of-filenames-in-a-given-folder-in-jenkinsfile-groovy)

Comment: Actually both could be fine. Actually I am getting following error message :

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call groovy from a windows batch or shell block with the script file as argument.

You may create a temporary script using the writeFile pipeline method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean , run external groovy file in jenkins pipeline or execute groovy sentences in jenkins pipeline?

Both could be fine. Actually I am getting this error message even if "new java.io.File java.lang.String
" signature has been approved :

```
Scripts not permitted to use method java.io.File listFiles. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.io.File listFiles
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:17)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor595.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Admin needs to edit and re-save your pipeline, also uncheck "run in sandbox" then it should works