# Get dir content in cross-platform Jenkins

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, cross-platform

We have a Jenkins Master on linux and Jenkins Agent on Windows for building C# applications.
(before that we've had master and agent on the same Windows machine)

In pipeline I have this code

```
def getFilesNamesFromDir(dir)
{
    def fileNames= []

    new File(dir).eachFile() { file -> 
        fileNames << file.getName()
    }

    return fileNames
}
...

def testDir= "${env.WORKSPACE}/test"

    try
    {
        testResults= getFilesNamesFromDir(testDir)
    } catch (err) {
        println(err.toString());
        println(err.getMessage());
        println(err.getStackTrace());
        error "Error"
    }
```

and after that in logs I got:

```
[Pipeline] echo
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/c:\jenkins\workspace\app-name_4.2.1/test
[Pipeline] echo
/var/lib/jenkins/c:\jenkins\workspace\app-name_4.2.1/test
[Pipeline] echo
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@311b5ad0
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
```

Within old setup it was working.

Where it's code is running? On the agent or on the master? How to fix this?

I need to get file list from a directory. But I've got an error.

Comment: Groovy code always runs on master. Use [`findFiles`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) to list files in agent workspace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List files on the workspace on a Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679991/list-files-on-the-workspace-on-a-jenkins-pipeline)